# Xcode 4.2 - why didn't this show a warning?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am using Xcode 4.2 and ios5 sdk beta 4 (snow_leopard).

I have strange problem when using Xcode.

・source file open and build
　　Xcode displayed warning message.
　　"warning: Deprecations: 'initWithFrame:reuseIdentifier:' is deprecated"

・but, this source file close and build
　Xcode does not display warning message

what should I do.
　[file open -> build] × all files?...

How can I display all warning message without source file not open in Xcode?.

Comment: you should ask your question at https://devforums.apple.com/community/ios/ios5beta/tools xcode 4.2 and iOS 5.0 is under nda.

Answer (score 0):

Deprecations are normally Disapproved in the newer version of the framework. Normally in each new versions when the methods are found to be ambiguous or not useful or some problems with those methods are deprecated/disapproved in newer versions...  They are just the warning and most of the time does not give error..

But in the Next release of the framework they will totally DISCONTINUE with those methods which are Deprecated in current versions.... This is same for all of the Programming world...

Comment: He's not asking what deprecation is. He's asking why Xcode only *sometimes* warns him when he's using a deprecated feature.